# A continuous function on $[0,1]$ which is non zero at a countable number of points.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove that a real continuous function on $[0, 1]$ which vanishes everywhere except at a countable number of points is the zero function. 
This result I am able to prove for a finite number of points. How do I prove it for countable number of points? Help please!

Comment: Hint: Can a non-constant continuous function on $[0,1]$ obtain only countably many values?

Comment: Thank you! I got the message. This is the most elegant proof in my opinion. The interval is connected. Hence its continuous image is also connected. Image has to be an interval or singleton!!The hypothesis hence leads me to conclude that it must be the constant zero.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: If $f$ is non-zero, can you find a open set in which $f$ is non-zero?

Comment: That’s where I have a difficulty. If the point ‘a’ where f is non zero happens to be a limit point of the countable number of points where f is non zero, then how do I get an open set in which f is non zero??

Comment: @LawrenceMano: consider in this way: if $f(c) \neq 0$ then by continuity we have a neighborhood $I$ of $c$ such that $f$ is non zero in whole set $I\cap[0,1]$ (and this set is uncountable). The proof rests on the fact that if an interval contains two distinct points then it is uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

Take a point $a\in [0,1]$. We need to calculate the limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $a$.

I will prove the limit is $0$, to do this we take a sequence of points $a_n$ such that $f(a_n)=0$.

This can be done by taking a point in $a_n\in(a-1/n,a+1/n)\cap[0,1]$ such that $f(a_n)=0$ (there must be such a value since there is an uncountable number of points in that set.

Answer (score 0):

Removing all points of $[0,1]$ where $f$ does not vanish results in a countable union of disjoint open sets, therefore it is open and its completion is $[0,1]$. Since this set is also the inverse image of the closed set $\{0\}$, it must be closed. Therefore, it is equal to its completion, hence the contradiction.

**Edit**: As *mlk* pointed out, this proof is flawed by the assumption that removing a countable set of points of $[0,1]$ results in an open set. This is not true in general as the case of $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ clearly shows. Another counterexample can be given by removing points of a convergent sequence $x_n\rightarrow x$ in $[0,1]$ for which $x_n\neq x$.

However, a short proof can be given using topology arguments.

Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed. Therefore, $[0,1]\setminus f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is open and countable. But every nonempty open subset of $[0,1]$ is uncountable, that is $[0,1]\setminus f^{-1}(\{0\})=\emptyset$.

Comment: Sadly that does not work, infinite sets are just to weird sometimes. Removing the countable set $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ from $[0,1]$ results in the set of irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ which in particular has no open subsets. In fact since you seem to be thinking of intervals, the best way to describe it is as an uncountable union of point sets, none of them connected to the next.

Comment: Thanks, I have been edited my answer.